# How to remove error in argparse during program execution

Tags: python-3.x

not able to remove the error in this argparse command

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('board')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    sudoku = Sudoku(args.board)
```

error showing:

> usage: sud.py [-h] board
>
> sud.py: error: the following arguments are required: board

Comment: I formatted the message to more clearly show the usage message and the error.

Comment: Did you try providing a `board` to the program?

Comment: just use "python sud.py thisIsABoard"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are asking argeparse to parse and validate a required argument, so it is correct that it gives you the error.

See the [argeparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags) on optional vs positional (i.e. required) parameters.

If your `board` argument is meant to be optional, you could do this instead:

```
parser.add_argument('-b', '--board')
```